# Angular "angular.js:14110 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined" exception on controller instantiation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting up a new MVC 5 project using Angular and TypeScript, and I am having issues instantiating a controller and a service. I get the following error when I include the ng-controller in my HTML:

```
angular.js:14110 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
```

Here's my setup:

app.ts:

```
module mqApp {
    'use strict';

    if (typeof (angular) != "undefined") {
        var modules;

        modules = [];

        angular.module("mqApp", modules)
            .controller("MasterController", MasterController)
            .service("UserService", UserService);
    }
}
```

userService.ts:

```
module mqApp {

    'use strict';

    export class UserService {
        public static $inject = [
            '$scope',
            '$http',
            '$window'
        ];

        private scope: angular.IScope;
        private httpSvc: angular.IHttpService;
        private window: angular.IWindowService;

        constructor($scope: angular.IScope, $http: angular.IHttpService, $window) {
            this.scope = $scope;
            this.httpSvc = $http;
            this.window = $window;
            alert(2);
        }

        logOff() {
            this.httpSvc.get('/Account/LogOff');
            this.window.location.href = '/';
        }

    }
}
```

masterController.ts:

```
module mqApp {
    'use strict';

    export class MasterController {
        public static $inject = [
            '$scope',
            'UserService'
        ];

        private userService: UserService;
        private scope: angular.IScope;

        contructor($scope: angular.IScope, userService: UserService) {
            alert(1);
            this.userService = userService;
            this.scope = $scope;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is spelled wrong in MasterController.ts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that typescript translates your `UserService` to something similar to

```
var UserService = function($scope, /* ... */) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    // ...
}
```

In JavaScript, one can use a variable that is defined with `var` before its definition, but the value will be `undefined`:

```
console.log(UserService); // => undefined
class UserService {}
console.log(UserService); // => function() { .... }
```

Thus, the order of imports matters: You have to make sure the code that defines your classes is executed *before* calling `.service(...)` or `.controller(...)` (it has to be positioned literally above the calls).

If you want to use classes and split them over files I recommend to use typescripts `import` mechanisms and a module loader system like `amd`. This ensures that the classes will be defined when used.